# Is there an enolate equivalent for enamines?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability, periodic-trends

I'm learning that enolates are stronger than enamines are stronger than enols in terms of general nucleophilicity. Makes sense. But what I can't find any explanation for online is why the trend shouldn't keep on going past enolates. Why isn't there a name for the species of enamine deprotonated on its heteroatom the same way there is for enols? (enols -> enolates, enamines -> ?)

[image]

I would imagine this species does not exist for some reason having to do with stability. Any explanation
or reasoning would be greatly appreciated and would help me get into the subject more. Thanks.

Comment: That would be rather called imine α‐anion https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/poc.357

Comment: Enamines are formed from secondary amines.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enamine#Metalloenamines ; https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00262a025